# Sort csv files using vba

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have imported a bunch of csv files using the code below. They all have the same amount of columns, with the same indices. Now i need a makro to sort the rows by a specific column (a prompt to ask for the column index from which it is to be sorted would be nice, but not necessary).

```
   Sub CSV_Import()

        Dim dateien, i, lastrow
        lastrow = 1
        dateien = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        ("csv-Dateien (*.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=True)

        Dim filename As String

        '******************************************************'
        filename = "D:/path/merged.csv"
        '******************************************************'

        Dim oFso: Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim oSourceFile, oTargetFile
        Set oTargetFile = oFso.CreateTextFile(filename, True)
        Dim sArray()

        If IsArray(dateien) Then
            For i = 1 To UBound(dateien) 
                ReDim sArray(0)
                Set oSourceFile = oFso.OpenTextFile(dateien(i), 1) ' open for reading
                While Not oSourceFile.AtEndOfStream ' while there is data in the file
                    sArray(UBound(sArray)) = oSourceFile.ReadLine  ' add the line to an array
                    ReDim Preserve sArray(UBound(sArray) + 1) ' increase size of the array by 1
                Wend
                ' Now we have the whole file in an array
                If i <> 1 Then ' Keep header from the first import
                    For myLoop = 1 To UBound(sArray) ' Loop from 1 and we skip the header line in the file
                        oTargetFile.WriteLine sArray(myLoop) ' write array values into file
                    Next myLoop   ' repeat for each line in the array
                Else
                    For myLoop = 0 To UBound(sArray) ' Loop from 0 and we don't skip the header line in the file
                        oTargetFile.WriteLine sArray(myLoop) ' write array values into file
                    Next myLoop   ' repeat for each line in the array
                End If
            Next i    ' repeat for each file in dateien
        End If

        Call SortCSVFile()

    End Sub
```

I have googled a bit, but the information I found is not suitable for my problem.. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I understand your code, you transfer multiple .csv-files to another .csv-file? And you want the rows in your new .csv-file to be sorted after column X? Do you plan to import that file into excel? Because if not, that `excel`-tag is misleading and not necessary.

Comment: yes, correct. I'm coding the makro in excel, so i thought it was necessary.

Comment: Aaaand do you want to import the file to excel? Because then you can just use `AutoFilter`. If not, you would have to sort the data before merging the .csv-files

Comment: I would need to view it in excel to evaluate, yes. How do I use `AutoFilter`?

Comment: See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff193884.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the following code as per your requirement for multiple csv files.

```
Sub UpdateData()
    Dim wb_CSV, wb_Report As Workbook
    Dim Last_Row_CSV As Long

    Set wb_Report = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wb_CSV = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "mycsvfile.CSV")

    Last_Row_CSV = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row


    wb_CSV.Sheets(1).Range("A1:AE" & Last_Row_CSV).Copy
    wb_Report.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    wb_CSV.Close
    Set wb_CSV = Nothing

'***** Do sorting and other analysis here *******

    Set wb_Report = Nothing
End Sub
```